# Cassandra SSTables: how to read in c++?

Tags: visual-c++, cassandra

What is the structure of SSTable files? How I can read SSTables in c++ application?

Answer (score 2):

It's really an internal implementation detail, subject to change.  (E.g., recently it changed in 1.2.0, 1.2.5, and 2.0.0, as well as most major releases before that.)

The best way to see exactly what is written is to look at SSTableWriter.append; the read path is scattered here and there, but the write path all goes through that one method.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to implement loading data via CQL in my c++ application. That is why it is interesting how it works.

Comment: Also, SSTableWriter is server class. How client app uploads sstables? what is used on client side to pass data to the server?